# How do I make an emualator for a certain device?

Tags: android, eclipse

So I'm trying to make a new emulator in "Virtual Devcice Manager" in Eclipse. I want it to be the same as a certain device (same screen size, same android version installed as it is by default on that device etc.).

The device I'm trying to "re-create" as an emulator is Sony Xperia Z. I searched for the phone's specs and this is what I found:

> Android 4.1
>
> 12.7cm (5") screen

I then tried to create a new virtual device in eclipse and I don't have any of these options. The closest Android version that Eclipse lets you use for Virtual device is 4.1.2 and the closest screen size is 5.1" WVGA

If I created a virtual device like this, would it be good? Would an application that I ran on this virtual device behave the exact same way as on actual Sony Xperia Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of the "Virtual device manager" you should have a tab called  "Device definitions" which allows you to define a new device as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, this is basically what I was looking for. I found something even better though: [click](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/) but your answer will help me a lot in the future.